# How can I stop Brave remembering the blank page in the undo history on a new tab

Tags: brave

I run Edge on my Windows work PC, and Brave on my Ubuntu home PC, both set up to show a blank page in a new tab.  If I visit a URL in a new tab, the history initially:

- Contains only the new URL (so the back and forward buttons are disabled) in Edge.
- Contains both the blank page and the new URL (so the back button is enabled) in Brave.

I prefer the Edge behaviour. Can anyone tell me how to make Brave to behave like this?